# Android: XMLPullParser.END_DOCUMENT event never called

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

When trying to use **XMLPullParser** the `XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT` event is never called thus code that is suppose to be executed after while loop is never executed. How can I prevent this from happening?

Code Snippet:

```
    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            Log.i("app", "End");
            return farmers.getFarmers();
        }
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
             if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
             } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                 // Do something
             } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                 // Do something
             } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                 // Do something
             }
             eventType = xpp.next();
            }
        if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            Log.i("app", "End");
            return farmers.getFarmers();
        }
            return "Some data";
```

Why is return never called?

Comment: I have the same problem and no answer yet - my while loop is running infinite when checking for END_DOCUMENT, so this event type never happens. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mike sorry I don't have a way to help you as I completed that project a while back and looking at the source code I switched to using a `SAX` parser instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are enclosing the check for `XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT` in a loop that only runs if eventType is not `XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT`, so it will never run that statement.

You need to have
`if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {}` outside the loop.

Edit: I saw your edit. Huh, still not detecting the end of the document?.

Try restructuring the loop to use `while(true)`, and put

```
else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
//Do stuff here
break;
}
```

inside the loop.

That way, it gets through the whole list, and only leaves the loop when it hits END_DOCUMENT. If loops indefinitely, then I am out of ideas :P.

Comment: thx for the answer. But that still doesn't help. I've updated my question to reflect the changes I made.